# Azure AKS Client Secret expired - How to change?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, acs

I have a Kubernetes Cluster running on Azure (AKS / ACS).
I created the cluster using the Portal. There a aadClient was created automatically with a client secret that now expired.

Can somebody please tell me how to set the new client secret which I already created?

Right now AKS is not able to update Loadbalancer values or mount persistant storage.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AKS client credentials can be updated via command:

```
az aks update-credentials \
    --resource-group myResourceGroup \
    --name myAKSCluster \
    --reset-service-principal \
    --service-principal $SP_ID \
    --client-secret $SP_SECRET
```

Official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/update-credentials#update-aks-cluster-with-new-credentials

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of doing that yet, officially supported, at least.

https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/371

EDIT: this answer is outdated, this is now possible